# OSX - turn off command key in terminal emacs

Tags: key-bindings, osx

I'm trying to disable the command key when running emacs from the terminal. Whenever I mistakenly press CMD-V instead of ALT-V, the text from my Mac clipboard gets copied into the buffer. From related questions, I've tried adding setq mac-command-modifier 'none or 'meta and setq ns-command-modifier 'none to my .emacs file. There is no effect. How can I disable the command key in emacs? If I can't disable it, can I rebind CMD-V to do nothing?

Comment: I don't use Emacs in the terminal, but this works in the GUI version to effectively disable Command+v by causing it to do nothing except execute the function **ignore**:  `(global-set-key [?\s-v] 'ignore)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but adding this to my .emacs did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it just your terminal program pasting the text into the terminal? I'm not sure emacs can stop it.

If you are using iterm, one option is to create a separate profile for emacs, then under "Keys" bind command-V to `ignore`. You obviously would only want to run emacs under this profile to maintain normal pasting in other terminals.